# How can I check if the ID's of a table match another ID's of another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have 4 parameters, one of them its given as an input parameter of a stored procedure (its like a code that represents an unique action), and I need to match these ID's with another ID's in another table, so I need to check in table 2 the ID's "DeliverTypeID", "ScheduleTypeID", "CourseID" if they are all the same as table 1, if they really are then it should print me out the corresponding records.

I need to do this selection by a Stored Procedure.

Here's my code so far:

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[nameSP]  ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameSP]  
    @ScheduleID int
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @DeliverTypeID int
    DECLARE @ScheduleTypeID int
    DECLARE @CourseID int

    SELECT @DeliverTypeID = DeliverTypeid
        , @ScheduleTypeID = [Cod Tipo Acção]
        , @CourseID = [Cod Curso]
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.[CourseID] = table2.CourseID
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.[ScheduleTypeID] = table2.ScheduleTypeID
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.[DeliverTypeID] = table2.DeliverTypeID
    WHERE table1.[Cod Acção] = @ScheduleID
    AND (CourseID = @CourseID OR table2.CourseID is null)
    AND (ScheduleTypeID = @ScheduleTypeID)
    AND (DeliverTypeID = @DeliverTypeID)
END
```

Minimal Example :

```
Table1

ScheduleID|CourseID|DeliverTypeID|ScheduleTypeID|
67212     |2000    |1            |1             |
69212     |3000    |2            |2             |
69124     |4000    |3            |3             |
70124     |5000    |4            |4             |

Table2
|CourseID|DeliverTypeID|ScheduleTypeID|
|3000    |1            |1             |
|2000    |2            |3             |
|5000    |3            |2             |
|NULL    |2            |1             |
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results (as formatted text **not** images). And explain what you are stuck on... seems you haven't yet written the second query to get the data you need?

Comment: I edited the second query that I've made and didnt work at all. Maybe that will help you clarify it. I forgot to mention that the 3 ID's can be null

Comment: You can't assign and use a variable in the same query... surely you want 1 query to get values for them and the second to use them as a filter? And seriously please provide a [mre] **including** sample data and desired results. For example are all 3 matching columns always present and equal? Or could they sometimes be missing?

Comment: I included 2 tables in my post as an example , sometimes the courseID can be null. Is that enough?

Comment: The Schedule ID will be always given , I'll give it in my program always.

Comment: No , it wasn't intentional. Already edited it! Sorry !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following. I don't think you need the variables, just the correct logic in your single join (it seems unlikely you want to join Table2 on 3 times).

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameSP]
(
    @ScheduleID int
)
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    -- Select specific columns you wish to return rather than *
    SELECT t2.*
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.CourseID = t1.[CourseID] OR t2.CourseID IS NULL)
        AND t2.[ScheduleTypeID] = t1.ScheduleTypeID
        AND t2.[DeliveryTypeID] = t1.DeliveryTypeID
    WHERE t1.ScheduleID = @ScheduleID;

    -- Tell the calling context that the SP executed OK (0 means OK any other number means error).
    RETURN 0;
END;
```

Note I recommend the use of table aliases for clarity.

Comment: Worked for me @Dale K. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: And you get the same comment as I made in the other answer - replacing the best practice of specifying the columns in the select list with "*" is a "downgrade"

Comment: @SMor its not clear that OP *was* selecting specific columns, because they are also attempting to assign them to the variables that they using in the where clause. The question just said they wished to obtain the corresponding records. Hence why I added a comment "instead of * please list the columns" because thats the most accurate answer that can be provided given the lack of clarity in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Separate the steps out. First assign the values, then check for records.

```
DECLARE @DeliverTypeID int
DECLARE @ScheduleTypeID int
DECLARE @CourseID int

SELECT @DeliverTypeID = DeliverTypeid
        , @ScheduleTypeID = [Cod Tipo Acção]
        , @CourseID = [Cod Curso]
FROM table1
WHERE table1.[Cod Acção] = @ScheduleID

SELECT CourseID, ScheduleTypeID, DeliverTypeID -- and other columns you want from table 2
FROM table2
WHERE (CourseID = @DeliverTypeID)
    AND (ScheduleTypeID = @ScheduleTypeID)
    AND (DeliverTypeID = @CourseID OR table2.CourseID is null)
```

If you are running a version of SQL Server that supports it (you don't mention the version you are using), then you could run `IF EXISTS` before the second query to handle no records.

Comment: Not a very set-based way of operating.

Comment: All supported versions isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

This is the correct form of your procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameSP]  
    @ScheduleID int
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *       
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.[CourseID] = table2.CourseID 
    AND table1.[ScheduleTypeID] = table2.ScheduleTypeID
    AND table1.[DeliverTypeID] = table2.DeliverTypeID
    WHERE table1.[Cod Acção] = @ScheduleID AND table2.CourseID is null
RETURN
END
```

Use the following command to run

```
exec nameSP 5
```

Comment: OP has used the best practice of specifying the actual columns to be retrieved. You have replace that with "*" which will select more (perhaps MANY more) columns, including the the duplicated join columns. It would also greatly help someone understand and learn from your code if you explained clearly what you changed and why.

Comment: I did not know the exact columns of the table and left it to the questioner to retrieve the desired columns.

Answer (score -1):

So there is one other issue you and seemingly nobody else seems to be even thinking about dealing with and it's bigger than you think, not obvious and can completely mess up your server and get you axed real fast.

```
 @ScheduleID int
```

I know right one line, so little information for such a big problem.

**[Parameter Sniffing.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd7xqLT_-2k)** - *(Yes it's nearly an hour long I will break it down)*

You may not have heard of this, but it may destroy every process that hits any table your Stored Proc is hitting.

**What is Parameter sniffing...**

Well imagine a Gardener (Server Core) Upper management (You) makes a Procedure to "Dig up Weeds"...

Middle Managers (Server Engine) Look at the first garden and it's 10ft square and Two Weeds, so they Compile the task based on this result, gives 1 Gardener *Joe* the tool shed key and tells them to grab a trowel, off to work they go like a little lemming determined to finish with no idea of timeout, there are only two weeds so you are Optimised for this result...

The Middle Managers - Store this Plan in their Gardening Plan Cache based on the Parameter Digging up Weeds...

If you ask the Middle Manager what Procedure do you use to "Dig up weeds", they say *"A trowel and a Gardener"*... **Points at Joe**

> Joe: "Hello"

Job 2 comes along and it's a 278 Acre Golf Course, they look at this new task and give the Gardener the key to the tool shed and tell him to get his Trowel, he jumps to it as fast as he physically can WITH NO CONCEPT OF TIMEOUT and gets to digging up weeds...

Another Gardener wants to get to work but this little guy plugging away forever has the Key for the shed, Golfers want to play but he is on the green and you can't play when he is Pulling up weeds, Bob the Janitor want to add new tools into the shed but we can't get in because Joe Digging up Weeds over there is running about digging up weeds.

So now you are Blocking other Gardeners, Golfers and Purchasing from doing their thing until you are done, well while purchasing is waiting for the Key to the Shed now in a small queue of Gardeners and other people, another Purchasing task starts and now they are stuck in a queue waiting for this guy to finish waiting for the Shed Key because he has the purchase ledger.

And then accounting gets stuck behind them and before you know it the whole Company (System) grinds to a halt because Joe has the damn key for the tool shed and now everyone is pulling overtime waiting for him to dig up a golf course with a trowel...

But it's not Joes fault he is doing his job dilligently you can't sack him for doing as he is told.

Well it can get worse than blocking, you can deadlock on Stored Procs and you can Corrupt tables.

And if you think well we can rollback... RollBack is Single Threaded!!! So Joe will be running around REPLANTING ALL THE WEEDS HE JUST DUG UP!!!

So whenever you design a Stored Proc always ADD `With Recompile` wherever a parameter is used and seeing as this is a Stored Proc, that should be ALWAYS!

Just think about it like this, the Middle Managers will re-assess the task each time and go oooof this is big job best get the whole team in parallel on lawn mowers... And nobody gets a Paddling.

Then at least when the next small 10ft garden comes up... you haven't got 500 Gardeners rock up on ride on lawn mowers.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameSP]  
    @ScheduleID int
    WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT CourseID, ScheduleTypeID, DeliverTypeID, Cod Acção    
    FROM table1
    INNER JOIN table2 on table1.[CourseID] = table2.CourseID 
    AND table1.[ScheduleTypeID] = table2.ScheduleTypeID
    AND table1.[DeliverTypeID] = table2.DeliverTypeID
    WHERE table1.[Cod Acção] = @ScheduleID AND table2.CourseID is null 

RETURN
END
```

Comment: Absolutely not! `With Recompile` should be used sparingly and carefully. And it can be explained a lot simpler than that. And as an answer its not relevant to the question.

Comment: Actually in most cases With Recompile is fine, OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN (OPTIMIZE FOR MEDIOCRE as Brent Ozar put it)  because, outliers will again cause the same Parameter Sniffing issues and this is for handling those.

IF  PARAM = X EXEC A PROC ELSE B PROC options for Bulky Procs is a maintenance nightmare because not only do you have to account for changes in data sets, but then you have to be careful to account for IF/ELSE Parameter Sniffing where the first result caches.

If there is a production level frequent use Recompile it's the best of the all the bad options.